# After compiling with -cp can't find classes

Tags: java, class, cmd

I am learning Java and one of the requirements for us is to know how to compile everything though command line.
I have in disk c a projects folder and my main is in

```
C:\Projects\Java\cinema\src\
```

I also have a "system" package, in which there are 4 classes. Package path:

```
C:\Projects\Java\cinema\src\system\
```

I am trying to compile my program into a bin folder.

```
C:\Projects\Java\cinema\bin\
```

In cmd I am at C:\ directory and I write this:

```
javac -cp Projects\Java\cinema\src\system\*.java -cpProjects\Java\cinema\src\Cinema.java -d projects\java\cinema\bin
```

Code compiles without errors, but I can't find my Cinema.class and one other class from package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the multiples `cp`

```
javac Projects\Java\cinema\src\Cinema.java Projects\Java\cinema\src\system\*.java -d Projects\Java\cinema\bin
```

Notice that I fixed the case of your path. Even if it works on windows, it would not on Unix system so it is a good habit to take to respect the case.

Comment: Ok. I am certain that everything you wrote is right, but now I am getting a compilation error regarding Ticket class in my Cinema class. Compiler "can't find symbol" when I write **Ticket ticket = new Ticket();**
I imported all of the classes to my main using **import system.*;** and I included Ticket into the package using **package system;.** Everything worked before, when I didn't use packages and compiled everything from one folder using **javac *.java**

Comment: @RičardasMikelionis If you change your import to `import system.Ticket` does it give an error on the import statement ?

Comment: Gives another error at **import system.Ticket** also can't find symbol.

Comment: Nope. It is still the same. But when I commented **/* */** statemets, that used Ticket class it compiled and ran.

Comment: They, you mean my Cinema class and my Ticket class? And what do you mean they were in the same package?

Comment: No they aren't. My Cinema.Java file is in src, and my Ticket.java, Movie.Java, Shedule.Java and Theatre.java are in src/system. But after i basically deleted all statements where I use Ticket class methods it worked.

Comment: What happen if you try directly with `javac Projects\Java\cinema\src\Cinema.java Projects\Java\cinema\src\system\*.java -d Projects\Java\cinema\bin`

Answer (score 1):

```
javac -d C:\Projects\java\cinema\bin C:\Projects\Java\cinema\src\system\*
```

should be enough